# ASP NET Core 2 with Full Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am unable to find any documentation, or examples, of an ASP.NET MVC Core app running under the full framework. It is supposed to be supported, but as I said I cannot find any documentation of how to configure a project for this, and have not been able to work it out myself.

Has anyone got this working and can provide advice/sample on what needs to be done?

Comment: Microsfot is not supporting it any more: https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/05/ASPNET-Core-2

Comment: @MuhammadNouman they came out and corrected that announcement a few days later and confirmed it would have full framework support. Someone obviously forgot to mention to the documentation department.

Comment: Than see this: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20

Comment: Found some documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework) stating this is still supported

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am able to create/run ASP.NET Core 2.0 project with Full .NET framework 4.6.1, I followed below steps-

1. Created new project using ASP.NET Core web application under Web category-

[image: Step1]

2. On 2nd step, selected Web Application (Model-View-Controller)

[image: Step2]

3. csproj looks like this- `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>`

[image: Step3]

My Environment is-

- Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.3.3 version
- .NET Core 2.0 SDK

Comment: We did this but we then had errors that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` cannot be referenced (saying it isn't compatible with chosen full framework). Then we removed the nuget reference for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` and added the missing nugets manually (look at the original project and see where exactly the assemblies get resolved to and add just that nuget - e.g. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore`, etc... kudos to  https://www.queryxchange.com/q/27_45776966/convert-a-quot-dotnet-new-angular-quot-project-to-net461/

Comment: Tried again recently when I had some time and VS and packages have had a few updates since the initial release, and went smoothly this time to upgrade the Core 1.1 apps.

Comment: what about asp.net core 3. can that be run on the full framework? which version ?