# .net core website using full .net framework using session

Tags: c#, .net, session, session-state, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to activate session on my .NET Core project like this tutorial. https://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/
But I am using the full .net framework instead.

I installed this NuGet package to get `AddSession` on `IServiceCollection`.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Session -Version 1.0.0-rc1-final
```

But when i run the application i get this error when calling `AddSession` on `IServiceCollection`.

> 'Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=2.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Anders

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this can help you but on my project (Net Core 2.0), *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (2.0.0)* that contains *Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll*, is under the NuGet reference of *Microsoft.AspNetCoreAll (2.0.0)*.
The *Microsoft.AspNetCoreAll (2.0.0)* also contains the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session (2.0.0)*.
I think that you should use *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session*, not the *Microsoft.AspNet.Session*.

Comment: I tried to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session but i can´t use that because i am using the full .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection nuget package.

Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions -Version 2.0.0

Comment: I get the same error after I tried to install this.

Comment: To clarify, you are using Asp.NET 5?

Comment: No i am using .Net Core 2. But because i don´t want to use Entity Framework Core i need to use the full .Net Framework. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066679/asp-net-core-2-with-full-framework